# How to export gridview to excel and exclude footer

Tags: asp.net, excel

I want to export a gridview in asp.net to excel but exclude the footer row. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it hiding while exporting like this:

```
myFiles.FooterRow.Visible = false;
```

Something like this:-

```
private void ExportGridView()
        {
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            myFiles.FooterRow.Visible = false;

            //.........
        }
```